# get YouTube videoID from gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos (YouTube api)

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api

Using jQuery and YouTube api.

I've been trying for a while to simply get the ID's of the searched videos, seems like or either i'm blind or the guys from youtube wants us to work more than necessary ;-)

```
#search = 'mad max';

$.ajax({
    url: "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=" + escape($("#search").val()) + "&alt=json&max-results=30&format=5",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (data) {showVideoList(data)}
});

function showVideoList(data) {
    console.log(data);
}
```

I get lots of information but the videos ID's. Ok I can get it from:

```
data.feed.entry[0].entrymedia$group.media$player[0].url
```

But will have to use regExp and might change in the future. There is no property in this object where I can get just the videoID ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var id = data.feed.entry[0].id.$t.split('/').reverse()[0];
```

Comment: thanks Ŝime ! it work exactly as supposed. Although i was hoping to find a cleaner way.

Answer (score 1):

To add on to Šime's answer, you can use 'pop' instead of reversing the whole array:

```
var id = data.feed.entry[0].id.$t.split('/').pop();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is highly ranked on google it's worth noting that now youtube returns the videoid as:

```
feed.entry[0].media$group.yt$videoid.$t
```

Comment: I don't see it in the json... Maybe it's been removed?